# Pointer to related research (paper)

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, research

Recently, I was reading a paper ([arXiv:1804.03719](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719) [cs.ET]), which had the following quote (the most relevant part has been bolded),

> Quantum algorithms are often grouped into number-theory-based, Oracle-based, and quantum simulation algorithms, such as for instance on the excellent Quantum Zoo site [57], which is largely based on the main quantum algorithmic paradigm that these algorithms use. These paradigms are the Quantum Fourier Transform (QFT), the Grover Operator (GO), the Harrow/Hassidim/Lloyd (HHL) method for linear systems, variational quantum eigenvalue solver (VQE), and direct Hamiltonian simulation (SIM). The fact that most known quantum algorithms are based on these few paradigms in combination is remarkable and perhaps surprising. **The discovery of additional quantum algorithm paradigms, which should be the subject of intense research, could make quantum algorithms applicable across a much wider range of applications.**

I am very interested in exploring the topic of quantum algorithm paradigms. However, my usual approach of following the reference trail failed to unearth any relevant papers.

If anyone has any suggestions regarding where to look, or know any relevant papers, I would appreciate your input.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Arthur-1. You want to know about QFT, GO, HHL, VQE and SIM specifically right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Specifically, I'd like to read current research on new paradigms, other than those.

Comment: I guess your best shot will be the quantum zoo site : https://math.nist.gov/quantum/zoo/ . I am not sure how it is defined what algorithm becomes a paradigm but I suppose it will be listed here.

Comment: I appreciate the link, I'll check it out :D